# When Stack Overflow site is loading and I click on achievements tab I get navigated to Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When Stack Overflow site is loading and I click on the achievements tab I get navigated to Stack Exchange reputation tab, here is a GIF.

[image] .

I am on Firefox 72.0.2 (32-bit) and Windows 10 . Just to be sure I have tested in a private window. The same thing happened in the private window too.

Comment: Yeah, rather annoying, especially when the layout has showed correctly, I might not notice the tab indicating there is still loading. And if I see a message, I'd be focused on that *which is on the opposite side of where the loading indicator is*.

Comment: this is by design, the JS is still loading so you are considering the *fallback* link. You need to be patient until the page fully load

Comment: I think it would be better if nothing happened if I click on the achievements instead of navigating to stack exchange site .

Comment: The fallback link is necessary for folks who don't/can't allow JavaScript to run in their browsers or have very slow/unreliable connections.